# How can I save double values in a binary file?

Tags: matlab

I have a `double` values array and I want to save that array in a binary file.
After that, I wish to compress that file.

I have tried using `fwrite(fileID,nameofvariable,'double')`, but after doing this, I can't read nor compress the binary file.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge he tried `fwrite(fileID,nameofvariable,'double')`

Comment: @antonis_som What did you attempt to read and compress the file with

Comment: `fwrite` should work.  Can you be more specific on what you have tried to use for reading and/or compressing?

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect significant deflation from compression? Binary data tend to be quite compact as-is, unlike text files (simply because `1.563284727247224e-3` takes up 8 bytes, while `'1.563284727247224e-3'` takes up at least 40). Of course your data can always have some non-trivial patterns that allow it to be compressed significantly...

Comment: to add to @AndrasDeak comment, the compression gain will greatly depends on the variability of your data. Try saving in different files `A=rand(1000)` and `B=zeros(1000)` then compress them ... you will notice a significant difference in the compressed size (although the files contain the same number of elements).

Comment: @excaza I want to compress the file with LZO compressor.
I have already tried 
fileID = fopen(filename,'w');
fwrite(fileID,nameofvariable,'double');
but after the writting of the file no more compression can be done to that file.So I am trying other ways to store the data in the binary file in order to be compressible
fclose( fileID);

Answer (score 0):

Its is very simple. See the matlab documentation for file operations.

```
fileID = fopen(filename,'w');
fwrite(fileID,nameofvariable,'double');
fclose( fileID);
```

Comment: This works in theory, but the OP says that it doesn't work.  You should wait for clarification before posting an answer.